# I cannot delete schema from BizTalk Console

Tags: schema, biztalk, biztalk-2010, mscorlib

I have problem to delete schema from BizTalk 2010. 
I received below error.

> Failed to delete resource(s). (mscorlib)
>   Could not load file or assembly 'D01B_RECADV.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the path specified. (mscorlib)
>   The system cannot find the path specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070003)

Actually same issue I have if I will export msi from schema and try to upload it back. I already try to redeploy it from VS, it was success but I need to delete it from BizTalk.

Comment: Can you find the DLL in the global assembly cache (I assume not)?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the whole application that the schema is in?

Comment: Hello,dll existing in GAC i found it in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\BizTalk.EDISchemas.EFACT_D01B_RECADV\v4.0_1.0.0.0__5d9e127113d14656. And also i try t oremove whole app did not help.